# Dataframe not appending values to column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an empty dataframe that I've loaded into my code. If the user says a keyword, it'll append their value to a specific column in the dataframe. However, whenever the user says the keyword, it's not appending it. This is my code:

```
    c3 = pd.read_csv('c3_homework.csv')
    homework = input("")
    homework = homework.lower().split()
    grade_class = homework[0]
    subject = homework[1]
    work = homework[2:]
    work = ' '.join(work)
    print(grade_class)
    if grade_class == 'c3':
        if subject == 'math':
            print(work)
            c3 = c3.append({'math':work}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, please provide a MRE

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to make an empty csv?

You can create an empty data frame and save it as a csv file.

below is my suggestion code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
homework = input("")
homework = homework.lower().split()

grade_class = homework[0]
subject = homework[1]
work = homework[2:]

work = ' '.join(work)
print(grade_class)

if grade_class == 'c3':
  if subject == 'math':
    print(work)
    df = df.append({'math':work}, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('c3_homework.csv')
```

Comment: Let me try to see if that works.